# Convert Dictionary to Nested Dictionary using value lists as keys

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I need to convert to a nested dictionary.
I need to transfer the keys as keys, the values inside the list need to become more keys in my nested dictionary with empty value lists.

This is the code I have created so far:

```
dictionary = {'op': ['Office', 'General'],'r-1' : ['residential', 'industrial']} 
    
    nested_dic = {}
    nested_two = {}
    
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        print("1-\n",key, value)
        nested_dic.setdefault(key, nested_two)
        print("2-\n", nested_dic)
        print("***************************************************************************************")
        
        for v in value:
            nested_two.setdefault(v, [])
            print("3\n", nested_two)
            print("4-\n", v)
            print("\nnested dictionary:", nested_dic)
            print("***************************************************************************************")
            
    print(nested_dic)
```

The output I am getting looks like this:

```
{'op': {'Office': [], 'General': [], 'residential': [], 'industrial': []}, 'r-1': {'Office': [], 'General': [], 'residential': [], 'industrial': []}}
```

but I need it to be this:

```
correct_nested_dic = {'op': {'office': [], 'General': []},'r-1': {'industrial':[], 'residential': []}}
```

I am duplicating the values in the for loops but I haven't been able to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated,
thank you

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions @itprorh66. I wrote some code and now I am asking a question relating to where I am stuck again. Let me know if I should include any other info. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer!
I will post it just in case it is useful for somebody else:

```
dic_2 = {'op': ['Office', 'General'],'r-1' : ['residential', 'industrial']}

nested_dic_2 = {}

for key, value in dic_2.items():
    nested_dic_2.setdefault(key, {})
    
    for v in value:
        nested_dic_2[key].setdefault(v, [])

print(nested_dic_2)
```

output:

```
nested_dic_2 = {'op': {'Office': [], 'General': []}, 'r-1': {'residential': [], 'industrial': []}}
```